# Plotly adding second bar chart to candlestick chart but get error message

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to add a volume bar chart to my candlestick chart that is made using Plotly. I know this has already been addressed in a previous question but I get an error message:

`TypeError: add_traces() got an unexpected keyword argument 'secondary_y'`

Which is strange to me considering that this is used to get it to work and even in the documentation they use this. Here is my code:

```
import requests 
import json
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go




def get_candles(symbol, window, interval='1h'):
    url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines"
    end_time = dt.datetime.utcnow()
    delta = dt.timedelta(hours = window)
    start_time = end_time - delta
    start_date = str(int(start_time.timestamp() * 1000))
    end_date = str(int(end_time.timestamp() * 1000))
    limit = '1000'
    market = symbol + 'BUSD'

    req_param = {"symbol": market, "interval": interval, "startTime": start_date, "endTime": end_date, "limit": limit}

    text = requests.get(url, params = req_param).text
    data = json.loads(text)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.columns = ['open_time',
                    'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v',
                    'close_time', 'qav', 'num_trades',
                    'taker_base_vol', 'taker_quote_vol', 'ignore']

    df.index = [dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x/1000.0) for x in df.close_time]

    return df


def chart(symbol, interval='1h'):
    windows = {'1m': 1, '5m': 5, '15m': 15, '30m': 30, '1h': 60, '2h': 120, '4h': 240, '6h': 360, '12h': 720, '1d': 1440}
    chart = get_candles(symbol.upper(), windows[interval], interval)
    fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
    fig.add_traces(go.Candlestick(x=chart.index,
            open=chart['o'],
            high=chart['h'],
            low=chart['l'],
            close=chart['c']))
    fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=chart.index, y=chart['v']), secondary_y=False)
    fig.layout.yaxis2.showgrid=False
    fig.write_image("figure.png", engine="kaleido")
    
chart('bnb')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are using `fig.add_traces` when you should be using `fig.add_trace`